# How to pass variables to proxy server url?

Tags: angular, typescript, proxy-server

I'm trying to find a way to pass certain variables to my proxy so I could call API with some parameters, just like in the example below.

My proxy config looks like this:

```
{
    "/darksky/*": {
    "target": "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

In the service I'm calling this proxy like:

```
return this.http.get(`/darksky/${x},${y},${date}?exclude=hourly,daily,flags&units=auto`);
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass certain variables to url - x, y and date and some static settings, but in the console it shows:

```
[HPM] GET /darksky/53.1219648,18.0002529,2019-12-04T12:00:00?exclude=hourly,daily,flags&units=auto -> https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/
```

And the api returns that the request was wrongly formatted - because I'm missing these additional variables. Then how can I pass something to the proxy so the actual redirect could look like this:

```
https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKz/53.1219648,18.0002529,2019-12-04T12:00:00?exclude=hourly,daily,flags&units=auto
```

EDIT: angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "fe": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/fe",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fe:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/app/proxyServer/proxy.config.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "fe:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fe:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "fe:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "fe:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "fe"
}
```

Comment: How you are staring angular application? just `ng serve` ?

Comment: Yes, but I've added the proxy to the angular.json.

Comment: please post package.json start script

Comment: Sorry, I've read angular.json istead of package.json - I'm gonna check your answear then.

Comment: Try with `/darksky` or `/darksky/**` in proxy config

Comment: @NileshGodhani - both don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Plochie pointed out the issue and I've managed to find a solution:

```
{
    "/darksky/*": {
    "target": "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/darksky" : ""}
  }
}
```

Simply adding "pathRewrite" to "proxy.config.json" - just like in the above snippet does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Your console output is

```
[HPM] GET /darksky/53.1219648,18.0002529,2019-12-04T12:00:00?exclude=hourly,daily,flags&units=auto -> https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/
```

Which is correct, as after the arrow (->), log is showing the GET request

> `/darksky/53.1219648,18.0002529,2019-12-04T12:00:00?exclude=hourly,daily,flags&units=auto`

is proxy to host

> `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/` (after ->).

As this is what you have mentioned in `proxy.conf.json`, its working as you have written.

This is a request issue, your final request is

```
https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/darksky/53.1219648,18.0002529,2019-12-04T12:00:00?exclude=hourly,daily,flags&units=auto
```

which is wrong, as per Darksky api, the darksky keyword should not there in request.

Your request should be

```
https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/53.1219648,18.0002529,2019-12-04T12:00:00?exclude=hourly,daily,flags&units=auto
```

Comment: As I supposed - the problem stays the same. Putting "proxyConfig": "src/app/proxyServer/proxy.config.json" in the angular.json and starting it with just ng serve - is another way of doing the exactly same thing as you mentioned. The output in console nad response from API are exactly as previously have been. It's still can't read variables. The proxy works fine cause it redirects to the target - but how to append additional url to the target?

Comment: I tought that after -> it should be like: "://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY//53.1219648,18.0002529,2019-12-04T12:00:00?exclude=hourly,daily,flags&units=auto" <- as the whole request. Is there a way to check the actual full length request after proxying? Putting combination of these two urls in the browser returns the right answear but in the app it does not.

Comment: It means that when I call the api through the proxy - the api returns as if the request was wrongly builed - like for example I've been missing something in the url, but I put the exact same url into the browser it returns proper data. Does proxy somehow changes anything or it actually calls just "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/" - without additional parameters?

Comment: Is my answer making sense?

Comment: Yep, I understand the issue - since I wanted exactly to know how the url looks like after proxying it - I'm just trying to figure out now how to bypass that.

Comment: I've posted solution below for the problem.